# How to customize YUI calendar themes in Java Wicket

Tags: calendar, wicket, yui

Is there a way to customize YUI calendar Design, in Wicket7?
As far as i can see it comes with one css set and it really is not a burner.
The only way i could think about is to override the used css but i wonder if there are some more elegant solutions to, like themes.

Comment: Do I understand you want to replate the skin 'yui-skin-sam' of the calendar component that's used a default skin?

Comment: somehow jes - i would like to try some other skins and be able to define my own custom skin

Answer (score 0):

The skin is hardcoded in class DatePicker, if you want to change it, there is some workaround in changing classes to get it working.

**First think first**, you should create your own Behavior derived from *DatePicker*, see the source code https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/build/wicket-7.1.0/wicket-datetime/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/yui/calendar/DatePicker.java

Replacing *afterRender(Component)* is enough, but you should copy-paste the code from the Wicket class and just replace the skin.

**IMPORTNANT:** DO NOT CALL super.afterRender(component); because it renders
the HTML you want to replace!

```
public class SkinnedDatePicker extends DatePicker
{

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public void afterRender(final Component component)
    {
        // NEVER CALL THIS: super.afterRender(component);

        // Append the span and img icon right after the rendering of the
        // component. Not as pretty as working with a panel etc, but works
        // for behaviors and is more efficient
        Response response = component.getResponse();
        response.write("\n<span class=\"yui-skin-MYSKIN\">&nbsp;<span style=\"");

        if (renderOnLoad())
        {
            response.write("display:block;");
        }
        else
        {
            response.write("display:none;");
            response.write("position:absolute;");
        }

        response.write("z-index: 99999;\" id=\"");
        response.write(getEscapedComponentMarkupId());
        response.write("Dp\"></span><img style=\"");
        response.write(getIconStyle());
        response.write("\" id=\"");
        response.write(getIconId());
        response.write("\" src=\"");
        CharSequence iconUrl = getIconUrl();
        response.write(Strings.escapeMarkup(iconUrl != null ? iconUrl.toString() : ""));
        response.write("\" alt=\"");
        CharSequence alt = getIconAltText();
        response.write(Strings.escapeMarkup((alt != null) ? alt.toString() : ""));
        response.write("\" title=\"");
        CharSequence title = getIconTitle();
        response.write(Strings.escapeMarkup((title != null) ? title.toString() : ""));
        response.write("\"/>");

        if (renderOnLoad())
        {
            response.write("<br style=\"clear:left;\"/>");
        }
        response.write("</span>");
    }
}
```

**The second place** is, when you want to use it with *DateTimeField* you have to override the factory method *newDatePicker()*, copy-paste Wicket code is in place again, see https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/build/wicket-7.1.0/wicket-datetime/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/extensions/yui/calendar/DateTimeField.java

```
public class SkinnedDateTimeField extends DateTimeField
{

    /**
     * The DatePicker that gets added to the DateTimeField component. Users may override this method
     * with a DatePicker of their choice.
     * 
     * @return a new {@link DatePicker} instance
     */
    @Override
    protected DatePicker newDatePicker()
    {
        return new SkinnedDatePicker()
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            protected void configure(final Map<String, Object> widgetProperties,
                final IHeaderResponse response, final Map<String, Object> initVariables)
            {
                super.configure(widgetProperties, response, initVariables);

                DateTimeField.this.configure(widgetProperties);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Than use your SkinnedDateTimeField component instead of DateTimeField